# Configurable products Design App for Magento

Tags: magento, configurable, configurable-product

We are planning development of a jewellery design tool for a magento site. 
Something like gem vara has.We are looking towards some pointers as to what will be the best approach. We can use configurable products but the problem is with product images. For example, a pendant can have 10-12 different kind of stones and we want to give user instant view of his/her selections.
For example, if user selects a blue stone, we would like the stones on the pendant to be replaced and blue color stones loaded. 
There are two challenges - 
1. If we create all images, the combinations would cross 200K images per product.
2. If we try to merge two images, and replace only the stones on selection, how we will define their position for each product ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.1.0 new feature is introduced that is "Configurable Swatches".
you can set multiple images if you set configurable products in magento. you can also set diffetent images for all products. customers can select different images in product listing  page and product detail page. you can refer this link for more detail.

http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/configurable-swatches-guide-magento-1-9-1-0/